# unexpected token error while using bash inside a jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got this error `unexpected token \` while running this regex inside a jenkins pipeline

```
steps {
wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper','colorMapName': 'XTerm']) {
sh '''#!/bin/sh +x
   echo "$VERSION" | grep -Eq "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(-.*)?" '''
```

any hints please how to solve that,
i guess the backslash and the point are not resolved
thanks

Comment: I think you need to escape the backslashes in the string in Groovy. Try `[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+(-.*)?`

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4) for some of the quirks with quoting.